# Combinatorial identity with numerator doubled in binomial coefficient

Tags: commutative-algebra, binomial-coefficients

Let $F_m(x)=\binom{x+m}{m}$. Does anyone know how to prove or disprove that

$$
F_{m-1}(2x)=2^{m-1}F_m(x)+\sum_{d=2}^{\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \rfloor +1} \frac{(-1)^{d-1}}{2} \frac{m2^m}{(d-1)2^{d-1}} \binom{m-d}{d-2}F_{m-d}(x)
$$

**What I did :** I have the checked the identity for $m\leq 10$.

**Context :** If true, the identity would help me a lot into turning a recent [partial answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784373/periodic-sequences-resulting-from-a-summation-over-the-thue-morse-sequence/3245327#3245327) of mine into a full answer.

Comment: Have you tried applying snake oil? This looks pretty similar to some central binomial  coefficient identities which that method handles well.

Comment: @BadamBaplan Interesting idea, but I don't see how to implement it. $\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{x+m}{x}t^m$ is not a value I know

Comment: That's just $\frac{1}{(1-t)^{x+1}}$